# "Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.Init" in Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: java, web-services, jar

I created a web application using Netbeans 8.0.2 with JDK 1.8 and Glassfish 4.1.1. My application using webservice to store information on database. It works fine. So I had to updated netbeans tool to 8.2 version: now if I call my webservice to store information on database I got following exception:

**Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.Init**

My jar loaded in lib directory are following:

- activation-1.1.1.jar
- aopalliance-1.0.jar
- asm-3.3.jar
- avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
- bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar
- commons-codec-1.7.jar
- commons-email-1.3.3.jar
- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.4.jar
- commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- cxf-api-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-common-schemas-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-common-utilities-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-core-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-transports-common-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-rt-ws-security-2.3.3.jar
- cxf-tools-common-2.3.3.jar
- geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
- jasypt-1.9.2.jar
- javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.jar
- javax.json-api-1.0.jar
- javax.mail-1.5.2.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
- jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.18.jar
- joda-time-2.2.jar
- log4j-1.2.12.jar
- logkit-1.0.1.jar
- mail-1.4.5.jar
- neethi-3.0.3.jar
- ognl-2.6.11.jar
- opensaml-2.6.1.jar
- openws-1.5.1.jar
- oro-2.0.8.jar
- poi-3.12.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.12.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12.jar
- serializer-2.7.1.jar
- servlet-api-2.3.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
- spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-binding-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-faces-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-js-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-js-resources-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
- spring-webflow-2.4.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar
- stax-api-1.0-2.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- stax2-api-3.0.2.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
- woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar
- wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
- wss4j-1.5.11.jar
- wss4j-ws-security-common-2.0.1.jar
- xalan-2.7.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
- xml-resolver-1.2.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
- XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar
- XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
- xmlsec-2.0.8.jar
- xmltooling-1.4.1.jar

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tied recreating the gkassfish server?

Comment: Are you sure your original application was jdk1.8? Best to check the properties are not set to 1.7, I say this as it happened to me when I upgraded to 8.2

Comment: I'm sure, I compile my application with JDK 1.8, I check my web application in properiets -> Build -> Compile - > Java Platform

Comment: can you put more of the stacktrace?

Comment: I tried to add xmlsec-2.0.8.jar into glassfish domain lib and now exception is this: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory not found by org.glassfish.metro.webservices-osgi [282]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)

Comment: you need this one for that https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

Comment: I already add this jar but I get same exceptions. I try to add this jar in lib domain but nothing

Comment: I solved using Netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: @Diaboliko - If you're able, post your comment as the answer and mark your question as resolved. I also experienced this issue, spent hours trying to resolve it, and fixed it with your suggestion of downgrading to Netbeans 8.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 8.2 comes with Glassfish 4.1.1 and NetBeans 8.0.2 comes with Glassfish 4.1. I got it working running Glassfish 4.1 with NetBeans 8.2.